# How to size a table to fill the available area?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a web page that I wish the content to be able to be resized by the user.  The table gets created from php so it can be less than the available area, often it will be more.  The fiddle I made has more content than the available area (this post would not permit it due to the size) and it expands off the bottom of the screen.  I got the width to resize properly but the fiddle does not show it.  The problem can be reporduced with the css from the fiddle and the html there or the html here with the row for the table copied about 20 times.

I would like a scrollbar when the data exceeds the available screen area and the table to fit the content area.  I can only get the scroolbar to show up if I change the height from 100% to a fixed pixel length.  But then it will not resize.

I was able to resize the content with javascript but can not puzzle out how to fix the table.  I tried style.height and offsetheight but offsetheight is read only and style.height changes but the table does not.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v87t75b/1/).

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel=Stylesheet Type='text/css' href=ERP.css> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayPrint()
    {           
        document.forms["reload"].submit();
    }

    function ResizeTable()
    {           
        var calculatedWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - 300;
        var tableHeight = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content").style.width = calculatedWidth + 'px';
        document.getElementById("ImageData").style.height = tableHeight + 'px';
    }

    if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', ResizeTable);
    } else {
        if(window.onload) {
            var curronload = window.onload;
            var newonload = function() {
                curronload();
                ResizeTable();
            };
            window.onload = newonload;
        } else {
            window.onload = ResizeTable;
        }
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header>

        <br>
        <form id='reload' name="Actions" action="Viewer.php" method="post">
            <span style='color:white'>Whole Number</span>


            <input type="text" id='WholeNumber' name="WholeNumber"    
                list="WholeNumberList" onchange="displayPrint()" 
                value="SS8618"">
            <datalist id="WholeNumberList">
                <option value=SS9230>
            </datalist>
        </form>

    </header>

    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>

<div id="content">

<Table id="ImageData" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td>
    <Table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="2">
        <TR><TH class='medium'>Whole Nbr</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Type</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Size</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Revision</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Other Nbr</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Sheet Nbr</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Of Sheets</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Frame Nbr</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Of Frames</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>Doc Title</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>Volume</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Note</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Prnt</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Obs</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>FilePath</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>FileName</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>FileExtension</TH>
        <TH class='small'>Base Doc</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>Acc Doc Nbr</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>CommonSubDirectory</TH>
        <TH class='medium'>LatestImage</TH>
        </TR>
    </Table></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="scrollingTable">
        <Table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="2">
            <TR><TD class='medium'>SS8618</TD>
            <TD class='small'>DD</TD>
            <TD class='small'>A</TD>
            <TD class='small'>4</TD>
            <TD class='small'></TD>
            <TD class='small'>7</TD>
            <TD class='small'>12</TD>
            <TD class='small'>1</TD>
            <TD class='small'>1</TD>
            <TD class='medium'>BONDING, ADHESIVE, OF ACOUSTIC INTERIOR</TD>
            <TD class='medium'>63642</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD class='small'>No</TD>
            <TD class='small'>No</TD>
            <TD class='medium'>200312ACD\52819</TD>
            <TD class='medium'>0060</TD>
            <TD class='medium'>PDF</TD>
            <TD class='small'>Yes</TD>
            <TD class='medium'></TD>
            <TD class='medium'>\CDVolumes</TD>
            <TD class='medium'>0</TD></TR>
        </Table></div></td></tr></Table>
    </div>

</div>

<footer>

    <br>

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for the scrollbar, you can set <tbody> to a specific height, and make overflow: auto;

Comment: maybe the calc() in CSS could do ? http://jsfiddle.net/5v87t75b/2/

Comment: calc() did it!!  Thanks GCyrillus!!